# Coldfusion regular expression order of precedence

Tags: coldfusion

We have a rereplace command like the following:

```
<cfoutput>
  #ReReplaceNoCase("www.one.two.three.four.com","(^www.)|(\..*$)","","ALL")#
</cfoutput>
```

The idea is to return the string "one", which the function does.

However, it seems ambiguous in that the (\..*$) could technically go all the way to the end of www.

Is there a defined order of precedence that states the "^" operator will be executed before the "&".

Note...reversing order of the substrings in the Regex does not affect the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to my knowledge.  It'll probably do them the normal way, i.e. try the first clause, then the second clause, depending on if it's using lazy evaluation (which it is).  Instead you'd be better to modify that second clause to be non-greedy, something like `(\..*?$)`